# How to change TFS Process Template

Tags: tfs, migration

I am about to move a local TFS project to visualstudio.com

When the project was created, it was created with a SCRUM process template. However, only source control functionality was used (except about 20 work items which can be deleted).

I want to add them to visualstudio.com as a project of process template type CMMI.

I am reading confusing (and seemingly conflicting) information on-line about how it is done (and if it is even possible).

Has anyone does this before (or have experience with TFS migrations in general)? Any input appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [TFS integration tool](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/eb77e739-c98c-4e36-9ead-fa115b27fefe) to process migrating Source control and work items. As you want to change the process template, you need to put the mapping file during migration. More information, you can refer to this blog: https://mohamedradwan.wordpress.com/2015/05/14/migration-to-vso-visual-studio-online-with-different-tools/